# outer join in a query builder with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join, outer-join, query-builder

I have an entity named `PointsComptage.php` and another one named `Compteurs.php`.

This is the relations between them:

```
// Compteurs.php 
/**
 * @var \PointsComptage
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PointsComptage", inversedBy="compteurs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pointscomptage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $pointsComptage;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ParametresMesure", mappedBy="compteurs")
 */
private $parametresMesure;

/*  ...  */


// PointsComptage.php
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Compteurs", mappedBy="pointsComptage")
 */
private $compteurs;

/*  ...  */
```

This is the query in my repository entity to recover the compteurs with their attributes for one pointComptage:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder
  ->select ('c')
  ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c')
  ->leftJoin('c.pointsComptage', 'pc')
  ->join('c.parametresMesure', 'pm')
  ->join('pm.typesUnite', 'tu')
  ->join('pm.typesParametre', 'tp')
  ->where('c.pointsComptage = pc.id')
  ->andWhere('pm.compteurs = c.id')
  ->andWhere('pm.typesUnite = tu.id')
  ->andWhere('pm.typesParametre = tp.id')
  ->andWhere('c.pointsComptage = :id')
  ->add('orderBy', 'c.miseEnService', 'ASC')
  ->setParameter('id', $id);

  return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                      ->getResult();
```

The problem is that I recover well my compteurs for the pointComptage selected, but only the compteurs which have parametresMesure relation.

In my database, it's **possible** that a compteur have **not** *parametreMesure datas*.

**How can I recover the compteurs which have not parametresMesure and the compteurs which have parametresMesure attributes (in the same queryBuilder)?**

I read on the doctrine documentation that a leftJoin in a queryBuilder works like a outer join.

That I am trying to do, is to recover all the `compteurs` linked to the `pointComptage` selected, whether or not the `parametresMesure`.

Comment: If you search SO for 'doctrine outer join' there are several answers. One of those will almost certainly help you.

Comment: Just use `leftJoin` instead of `join`

Comment: @PiWi Even if I use `leftJoin` instead `join` in my queryBuilder, my request returns me the same results, i-e just the **compteurs** which have **parametresMesure**, but I have well a **compteur** with no **parametresMesure** for the **pointComptage** selected before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that I added the condition in my `Where` clause, but I needed to specify them in my `leftJoin`.

Here my code to understand what I did:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder
    ->select ('c')
    ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.pointsComptage', 'pc', 'WITH', 'pc.id = c.pointsComptage')
    ->leftJoin('c.parametresMesure', 'pm', 'WITH', 'pm.compteurs = c.id')
    ->leftJoin('pm.typesUnite', 'tu', 'WITH', 'pm.typesUnite = tu.id')
    ->leftJoin('pm.typesParametre', 'tp', 'WITH', 'pm.typesParametre = tp.id')
    ->andWhere('c.pointsComptage = :id')
    ->add('orderBy', 'c.miseEnService', 'ASC')
    ->setParameter('id', $id);

return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

Like this I recover all my `compteurs` even if they don't have `parametresMesure`.

Comment: You found it yourself :-) I was just writing that answer myself ;-) If you use left joins this performs even better than filtering in the end.

Comment: Can you explain why we dont use ->Having('pc.id = c.pointsComptage') in place of using WITH ?